# Why do we need a "a" in "Oíste a los pajaros"?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, objetos-indirectos, animales

I am just learning Spanish from Duolingo.

Would this be incorrect?

> Oíste los pajaros

Can it be used in informal spoken conversations?

Answer (score 5):

That depends on whether the object is direct or indirect. Imagine you are camping in the middle of the forest, you could say:

> Anoche oí un lobo a lo lejos.
>   Anoche oí lobos a lo lejos.

You don't need the *a* preposition because in this case *un lobo* (or *lobos*) is the direct object of the sentence. But you could also say:

> Anoche oí aullar a un lobo.

Then *aullar* would be the direct object (what you hear) and *a un lobo* the indirect object (who produces the sound that you hear). You can't omit the preposition *a* in this case as every indirect object needs it.

In your example:

> ¿Oíste a los pájaros?

Here *a los pájaros* would be an indirect object while the direct object (the sound that you are actually hearing) is omitted. It could be something like this:

> ¿Oíste piar a los pájaros?

Actually, the Spanish grammar says that when the direct object is omitted in this kind of sentences, the indirect object (the birds here) works as direct object, but the *a* is still needed, although this time it's because when the direct object is a person (or a given subset of animals, as guifa points out [in his comment](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27122/why-do-we-need-a-a-in-o%C3%ADste-a-los-pajaros#comment45532_27123)), it needs the preposition.

You can also say:

> Estoy oyendo pájaros fuera de la ventana.

In this case you don't need to use the personal *a*. Note that the difference between this sentence and your example is that in the former the speaker knows about the referred birds, but in the latter the birds are something unknown.

Comment: There is no object. It is merely the second person of the simple past tense in Spanish.

Comment: I don't see how this answer was downvoted.

Comment: I think the first part of the answer might be confusing or misleading. There's no question that *los pájaros* in the question is a direct object.

Comment: @pablodf76 It certainly is.

Comment: @pablodf76 maybe I misunderstood the question. Re-reading my post it seems to answer a slightly different question about whether the _oír_ verb must be followed by an _a_ in general, and not in the particular case the OP asks about. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Then I'm interested in what you would have to say about the sentence "Estoy oyendo a los pájaros de afuera"

Comment: @Krauss that's answered in the last part of my post. If you say "estoy oyendo a los pájaros de afuera" it seems that you already know there are usually birds outside, whereas if you say "estoy oyendo pájaros afuera" then the fact that there are birds outside is somewhat a surprise to you.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to human direct objects, the personal a is also used with living non-human direct objects:

> Conversely if the nonhuman direct object is a live being (real or fictitious), it is preceded by the personal **a**. This is the case for animals and personified concepts:
>
> El cazador mató **a**l león.
>
> El científico vio **a** la Muerte.
>
> - [*Manual de gramática*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ScUaCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT53&lpg=PT53&dq=gram%C3%A1tica+a+personal+a), Eleanor Dozier, Zulma Iguina (p.26)

However, this rule is not steadfast for animals. It is almost always used for pets, animals with names, but how far it is extended to other animals varies from dialect to dialect, and even within an individual's speech:

> Cuando el silencio que uno lleva dentro es tan grande, puede no llegar a **oír los pájaros** que se hallan al lado. De todas, es la disciplina más ingrata, la de imponerse **oír a los pájaros.**
>
> - [*Los hemisferios de Magdeburgo*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WpsfAQAAIAAJ&q=%22o%C3%ADr+a+los+p%C3%A1jaros%22+%22o%C3%ADr+los%22), Andrés Trapiello (p.241)

Answer (score 1):

*Oír* takes an object; however, you can also use it with a preposition: *oí **una charla***; *oyó **a** la profesora*.

I can't confirm whether this is a rule or not, but you can use *oir* with no preposition when you refer to things; use *oir* + preposition when you refer to people or living things.

> —¿Oíste a los pájaros?
>   —¿Oíste los pájaros? (This sounds rather odd to my ears.)
>
> —¿Oíste la conversación?
>   —¿Oíste a la conversación? (Odd as well.)

Comment: This is the case of the *a personal*.  For some reason, some animals are more likely to take it (dogs, etc) and others are less likely (an ant or wasp).  People and the particular subset of animals (which may differ per person) require an *a* whenever they are the direct object.

Comment: @Lambie What do you mean? I'm baffled.

Comment: Ok, never mind.  Sorry. It's a with people or animals, as guifa says.